# WordPress Taxonomy, listing ONLY the single taxonomies

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

So I have a custom Taxonomy 'Sectors'.

I am trying to display all the single posts in 'Sectors' in a list, just a basic list.

I currently do have it so, it will display the category, then a sub category, then the list from there.

I also have this, which lists all posts - (NOT TAXONOMY) :

```
<?php 
      $uncat = get_cat_ID('uncategorised');
      $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'category__not_in' => array($uncat)
        );
      $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
      while ($loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
      ?>
      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" style="padding-left:0; padding-right:0;">
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
        <div class="postsize">
          <div class="leftfloat" style="float: left; padding-right:20px;">
            <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $page->ID, 'categoryimage', array('class' => 'faqposts')); ?>

          </div>
          <div class="contentfaq">
          <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
          <span class="entry-date-orange"><strong><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></strong></span>
          <?php
          foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
            echo ' | ' . $category->cat_name; 
          } 
          ?>

          <p style="margin-top:10px";><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        </div>
        </div>
      </a>
      </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

is there a way, to use this code below, to ONLY get items from the taxonomy 'sectors'?

Comment: I don't understand. You are using terms of the build taxonomy `category` inside the loop, but you are talking about a custom taxonomy called `sectors`. How are your `sectors` taxonomy and its terms related to the posts and the build in taxonomy `category`

Comment: Apologies, they are not.
This is the example I have, which gets my posts. I thought this may help to get the taxonomy 'Sectors' instead.

Comment: Not sure what you want here, but you could check out this: http://generatewp.com/wp_query/

Comment: @PieterGoosen I do have my posts displaying, but only via category. Would this be more of a help?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden I just need to display all the posts in my taxonomy 'sectors'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work, you will need to get all the terms belonging to your taxonomy, and then use a `tax_query` to query the correct posts. For effeciency, we will only get the term ids and not the complete objects

(***NOTE:*** The code is untested and requires PHP 5.4+. Also, just confirm the taxonomy name)

```
$term_ids = get_terms( 'SectorCategories', ['fields' => 'ids'] );
if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );
} elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) {
    $paged = get_query_var( 'page' );
} else { 
    $paged = 1;
}
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'sectors',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'SectorCategories',
            'terms' => $term_ids,
        ]
    ],
    // REST OF YOUR ARGUMENTS
];
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

### EDIT

For older PHP versions, use the following code

```
$term_ids = get_terms( 'SectorCategories', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
if ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) {
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );
} elseif ( get_query_var( 'page' ) ) {
    $paged = get_query_var( 'page' );
} else { 
    $paged = 1;
}
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sectors',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'SectorCategories',
            'terms' => $term_ids,
        )
    ),
    // REST OF YOUR ARGUMENTS
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

### EDIT 2

A very basic loop for the above query would look something like this

```
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    $loop->the_post();

        the_title();

    }
    next_posts_link( 'Next posts', $loop->max_num_pages );
    previous_posts_link( 'Previous posts' );
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Thank you,
but for some reason, I am getting a white page?
<?php
$term_ids = get_terms( 'sectors', ['fields' => 'ids'] );
$args = [
    'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'sectors',
            'terms' => $term_ids,
        ]
    ],
    // REST OF YOUR ARGUMENTS
];
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

Could this be because of PHP5.4+ (how do i check)

Comment: `echo phpversion()` in any template

Comment: 5.3.29,

Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Jip, it is, the new short array syntax is not available in versions before 5.4. In older versions you get a fatal error and a white screen. Will update my answer for lower versions. You should really think about upgrading. Al  versions prior to php 5.4 have been EOL'ed, so you are going to run into security issues down the line as all support has been stopped for those versions

Comment: Oh, I did not know that!
I will definitely look into it, I will finish this project off, back it up and look into upgrading :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82578/discussion-between-jdloader-and-pieter-goosen).

Comment: I don't understand your comment, can you please rephrase

Comment: Sorry, wrong question to ask!
You know how it is now just displaying every post from 'Sectors', can we somehow add sub pages as such, just the idea of showing for example 10 posts, and then buttons at the bottom

Such as:

<1 2 3 4>

Comment: You want to paginate the query in other words

Comment: Just looked it up, yeah that's right.
IS it just a plugin? :)

Comment: I have updated all three block of code to paginate. Check it out :-)

Comment: Works a treat :)
Is there a way to make them numbers? Any links to it would be more than enough, you've done loads :-)

Comment: I have done a post on [wordpress.se] regarding this issue. See it [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/172818/31545)

Comment: So the top one goes in Functions.php?

Comment: Crap, you can't use my approach. It needs PHP 5.4 at least, you do not have that. My function will break your site

Comment: Yeah I was just thinking that! Definitely upgrading when this is finished!

Comment: Use [this one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/134797/31545). It will work. Add the code in functions.php, then use it inside your template as `theme_pagination( $loop->max_num_pages );`

Comment: My pleasure. Enjoy :-)